# inconsistency between docker stats command and docker rest api memory stats

Tags: docker, ram

when looking at a running container with docker stats command, I can see that the memory usage of a container is 202.3MiB.
However, when looking at the same container through the REST API with 
GET /containers/container_name/stats -> memory_stats-> usage , the usage there shows 242.10 MiB.

there is a big difference between those values.
What might be the reason for the difference? I know that the docker client uses the REST API to get its stats, but what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you double check container id in both approaches?

Comment: Double checked it. I am running a single container for testing this issue. 
After trying the same thing now, I am getting very different results between the two  approaches. one is giving me 52.21% and the other gives 91.55%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved my problem. Initially, I did not take into account cache memory when calculating memory usage.

Say "stats" is the returned json from
GET /containers/container_name/stats,

the correct formula is:

```
memory_usage = stats["memory_stats"]["usage"] - stats["memory_stats"]["stats"]["cache"]

limit = stats["memory_stats"]["limit"]

memory_utilization = memory_usage/limit * 100
```

Comment: On IOS Docker and Windows Docker cache is not included.

Comment: This is not valid any more on Docker versions > 19.03. You have to use `total_inactive_file` not `cache`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **rss** value i.e (rss = usage - cache)

```
"memory_stats": {
        "stats": {
            "cache": 477356032,
            "rss": 345579520,
        },
        "usage": 822935552 
}
```

On Linux, the Docker CLI reports memory usage by subtracting page cache usage from the total memory usage.

The API does not perform such a calculation but rather provides the total memory usage and the amount from the page cache so that clients can use the data as needed. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect for recent Docker versions (version greater than 19.03).

The correct way that gets the same number `docker stats` reports is:

```
    memory = stats['memory_stats']['usage'] - stats["memory_stats"]["stats"]["total_inactive_file"]
    memory_limit = stats['memory_stats']['limit']
    memory_perc = (memory / memory_limit) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code according to the [Docker cli source code](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/20.10/cli/command/container/stats_helpers.go#L239):

```
  const memStats = stats.memory_stats
  const memoryUsage = memStats.stats.total_inactive_file && memStats.stats.total_inactive_file < memStats.usage
    ? memStats.usage - memStats.stats.total_inactive_file
    : memStats.usage - memStats.stats.inactive_file
```